# Omitted verbs? 想いを音に音は思いをわずかでもいい届いてくれよ！

Tags: grammar, particles, giving-and-receiving

> 想いを音に　音は思いを　わずかでもいい　届いてくれよ！

What I'm confused about is the omitted verbs. I saw a translation from a translator (from Wiki) going something like:

> "Turn your thoughts into sound, and your sound into your thoughts (this looks crappy already how can you turn sound into thoughts when 思い is an object) it's okay if it's not much, just as long as it gets through!"

Can you omit suru and can kureru be omitted like ageru?

Comment: i just realized oto wa can also be suru-ed cuz wa.. sometimes i confuse wa and ga lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

想いを音に means something more like "express your thought in sound". 音を思いに is even hard to understand even for Japanese people tbh. I guess it's trying to be poetic.

But what omitted here is not *suru*. 想いを音に**込めて** would be the full sentence. You can omit verbs like this, but only in things like songs, poems or slogans. It sounds weird if you just omit it in the middle of a normal sentence…

Comment: Welcome to the site and thanks for your answer! I did some copy-editing and styling changes, feel free to click on  "edited X mins ago" to see what I changed.

Comment: um, another question, without contexts, how do you understand things like this, suru and komeru in this situation, oto is adverb or way of doing and omoi is the object, how can i find it out!??!

Comment: so is suru literal?

Comment: It's a good qusestion. Suru means "do", so we can put it after noun(but only noun which already have meaning of action) "o". For example, 料理をする(cook), 化粧をする(make up). But here, 想いを音に misses the word of action since 想い is thought and 音 is sound. Also, 想いをxxに込める is a common phrase.